# Which type should I use on a Rails migration for a SecureRandom.hex(12) id, too short for a UUID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, migration, uuid

I need to import records from some huge CSV.
These records have an ID in this format: `056d024481a9` (looks like a `SecureRandom.hex(12)`)

I'm not sure what type I should use in the migration. It doesn't fit if I use `UUID` (it doesn't allow me to assign it into ID and save it) and I can't use `String` for Primary Key.

And example of my code is this:

```
order_attributes = row.to_hash.slice(:id, :amount, :created_at)
  orders_list.push(order_attributes)
end

processed_orders = Order.upsert_all(orders_list, returning: %w[id amount])
```

This piece of code doesn't work if I use UUID type for Order ID. I'm stuck with this, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

So first, you can use a string as the primary key.

But second, just turn it into an integer and store it in the default:

```rb
order_attributes[:id] = order_attributes[:id].to_i(16)
```

Note that you could also do this by creating a custom converter for CSV so it happens automagically during parsing.